# How to setup a Multilingual site using A LOT of taxonomy terms and CCK content taxonomy?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, i18n-l10n

I am going through the process now of translating my site into multiple languages. I have A LOT of vocabulary terms and I use them with Content Taxonomy CCK fields on my nodes. I don't believe I can have separate vocabularies as the content taxonomy CCK field on the node can only use ONE vocabulary to save to.

So what are my options? What is best practice? I have wanted to offer my site in multiple languages for a long time but just a bit confused.

Also regarding menu items, should I create a separate menu for each language or use the Translate interface and search for each menu text string and add translations. There seem to be multiple ways to do everything and I think this is adding to the level of confusion. Anyone that has done this before it would be a great help!

My site is a online directory of listings, so LOTS of content and a rather complicated interface, so I want to make sure I start this off right, rather than just going into it by guessing. Thanks!

---

Thanks for the link! But I think you misread the question. I am not referring to menus.

I'm having trouble using localize terms method on vocabularies with the Content Taxonomy field on my node. It's showing both the vocabulary dropdown list of the terms as well as the content taxonomy dropdown list of the terms. They are translating just fine and showing properly, but it shouldn't be displaying double the dropdowns. Content taxonomy should be hiding the Vocabulary dropdown. I am trying to figure out why it's not. any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Check this for taxonomy translation:
http://drupal.org/node/335205

The approach for menu translation depends on your menu and site structure. It is a bit painful but I would recommend using the menu translation interface. Managing multiple menus may work fine if you are planning 2-3 languages max but as you add more languages it will get out of control.